# Error in logcat

Tags: android

Every time i run my app the Null Pointer casts at logcat how can i know where the error is ive tried the debugging in eclipse but i still can`t figure it out ,

here is the logcat error at first the error i found was no such column exists i have fixed it now this is the error:

```
02-12 00:16:40.837: D/AndroidRuntime(360): Shutting down VM
02-12 00:16:40.837: W/dalvikvm(360): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception                (group=0x40015560)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.AndroidSQLite}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     com.example.database.AndroidSQLite.onCreate(AndroidSQLite.java:58)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-12 00:16:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(360):  ... 11 more
02-12 00:16:42.977: I/Process(360): Sending signal. PID: 360 SIG: 9
```

**here is my code:**

```
     package com.example.database;

     import android.content.ContentValues;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

     public class SQLiteAdapter {

      public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "SCORING";
      public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "SCORING_TABLE";
      public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 3;
      public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
      public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Content1";
      public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Content2";
      public static final String KEY_CONTENT3 = "Content3";

      //create table SCORING (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
      private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
       "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
       + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
       + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, "
       + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, "
       + KEY_CONTENT3 + "text not null);";

      private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
      private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

      private Context context;

      public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
       context = c;
      }

      public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
       sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,                                  MYDATABASE_VERSION);
          sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this; 
            }

       public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,             MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this; 
       }

       public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
       }

       public long insert(String content1, String content2, String content3){          

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT1, content1);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT2, content2);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT3, content3);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
       }

       public int deleteAll(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
       }

       public Cursor queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2,    KEY_CONTENT3};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
          null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
       }

       public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
          CursorFactory factory, int version) {
         super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // If you need to add a column
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SCORING_TABLE ADD COLUMN Content4 TEXT");
    }
        }
       } 
      }
```

now i got the second error in this part

```
02-12 00:54:03.516: D/AndroidRuntime(359): Shutting down VM
02-12 00:54:03.516: W/dalvikvm(359): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015560)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:130)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1584)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 00:54:03.546: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 00:54:05.646: I/Process(359): Sending signal. PID: 359 SIG: 9
```

and its class:

```
        package com.example.database;



    import com.example.database.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity {

     EditText  inputContent2;
     TextView textView1, textView2;
     Button buttonAdd, buttonDeleteAll;

     private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
     ListView listContent;

     SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
     Cursor cursor;

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);


           textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
           inputContent2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content2);
           buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
           buttonDeleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteall);
          listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

           mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
           mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

           cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
           String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1,         SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2};
           int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3};
           cursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
           listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

           buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
           buttonDeleteAll.setOnClickListener(buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener);



       }

       Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener
       = new Button.OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
             int a=Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
             int  b=a+2;
          String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
          textView1.setText(s1);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       String data1 = textView1.getText().toString();
       String data2 = inputContent2.getText().toString();
       String data3 = textView2.getText().toString();
       mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
       updateList();



      }

       };


       Button.OnClickListener buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener
       = new Button.OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
       updateList();
      }

       };

     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onDestroy();
      mySQLiteAdapter.close();
     }        



     private void updateList(){
      cursor.requery();
       }

    }
```

as for the xml layout here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >


<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="hello"
   />
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Enter content of column 1"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Enter content of column 2"
   />
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/content2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/add"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Add"
   />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/deleteall"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Delete All"
   />
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/contentlist"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your LogCat errors, they tell you exactly where the error occurs. Also please take a moment to properly format and indent your code then post it here in a code block (Ctrl+K).

Comment: Look at your log. You will se "Caused By" and it will give you a line number. Sometimes its not exact but it tell you where to look.

Comment: and you didn't think it could be relevant to actually post the stacktrace ?

Comment: (also : just read the darn stacktrace, while you're at it)

Comment: sorry i was looking at other posts

Comment: `at     com.example.database.AndroidSQLite.onCreate(AndroidSQLite.java:58)` The problem is on line 58 in AndroidSQLite, post this class and indicate which line that is if you still need help.

Comment: com.example.database.AndroidSQLite.onCreate(AndroidSQLite.java:58) .This is the line no where your error is.Post the code of AndroidSqlLite

Comment: @Sam, thanks for answer i have found out the error and it`s my Intent after that i got new error

Comment: Glad you found a solution. If you need help with the new error post the LogCat and relevant code. (Maybe someone else is going to repeat this comment for no reason what so ever, as has happened with my previous two...)

Comment: @Payal Thank to you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, you have three values in your `from` array, but four in `to`. These two arrays must match (with a one-to-one relationship):

```
String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3};
```

Comment: thank you so much Sam now i can move on

Comment: Progress is always a good thing. :) Please click the check mark to accept this answer.